# How to transfer video from not-my-iPhone to MacBook

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ios, photos

My friend plugged his phone into my macbook with a USB cable.

I opened Photos.app.

It is stuck on

> Preparing to import from "Phone name"

How can I get a video from the phone to the macbook painlessly and quickly? Airdrop was taking aeons and kept failing.

Comment: Was the phone asking whether to trust the Mac? did you accept that?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson yes